# Preserving color when redirecting output from stdout and stderror in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am wrapping a command line process in a WinForms app and redirecting the output so it can be piped into either an RTF control or a listbox. It would be nice to be able to preserve the foreground color of the text as it comes through so it can be displayed properly in the form. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably not. Colored console output is done using the [SetConsoleTextAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686047%28VS.85%29.aspx#_win32_character_attributes) API call, which operates on console screen buffers.

If you redirect output from a console application, you have no console screen buffer to work with. SetConsoleTextAttribute returns zero (indicating failure) if you redirect output, which means that the application could not even set colors.

Comment: Is there an alternative to redirecting output then? What about a hidden console window and scraping the output?

Comment: You might find a solution in the source code of Console2 (http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) a "Windows console window enhancement" that manages to implement console windows with colors, tabs, ...